# Build and order an array with the first element of other arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I'm trying to transform an array of 3 arrays in an array of 4 where each array is built and ordered with the first element of each other.

I have this:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

And I would like the following:

```
[[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11], [3, 6, 9, 12]]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Array#transpose`.

```
your_array.transpose
```

will do it.

Comment: Fastest answer, I have ever seen.. :-)

Comment: It is (perhaps) the first time I answered in less than a minute after the post. Usually, it takes two minutes untill I see the question posted.

Comment: You wouldn't want to damage your HHKB2. I suggest you let it cool for a few minutes.

Comment: @CarySwoveland At this particular moment, my HHKB2 is sleeping, and I am typing on Filco Majestouch.

Comment: Are those keyboard names? I guess so. :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit I am more excited about the fact that I am very close to being in the top five Ruby answerers. I was an inactive user for the first year, and overall, it took me four years and three months to reach this position.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
array.transpose
[[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11], [3, 6, 9, 12]]
```

Is this what you were looking for?